# Alfresco Share: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, alfresco

I'm using Alfresco 4.0d + MySQL + Win 2008 R2. About once a week in the logs this message appears:

```
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
    at java.net.Socket.bind(Socket.java:577)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.bind(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bind(SSLSocketImpl.java:45)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:399)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.ssl.AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:168)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.alfresco.httpclient.AbstractHttpClient.executeMethod(AbstractHttpClient.java:110)
    at org.alfresco.httpclient.AbstractHttpClient.sendRemoteRequest(AbstractHttpClient.java:86)
    at org.alfresco.httpclient.HttpClientFactory$HttpsClient.sendRequest(HttpClientFactory.java:307)
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1007)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackModels(CoreTracker.java:1630)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackRepository(CoreTracker.java:1134)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.updateIndex(CoreTracker.java:491)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTrackerJob.execute(CoreTrackerJob.java:45)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

After that, it is impossible to Alfresco Share login.
Tried fixpack, which is advised
https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-13666
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088363/java-net-socketexception-no-buffer-space-available-maximum-connections-reached
Does not help.
Please give advice on how to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried switching back to Lucene? I know the 4.0 community & enterprise series aren't fully bug-free with SOLR. Hence I would just try to set the search subsystems to lucene, restart and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in Windows 2008 R2.

I answered the question in this post: [java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): JVM_Bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088363/java-net-socketexception-no-buffer-space-available-maximum-connections-reached)

Comment: Ah sorry, just noticed you tried that already. Try disabling multithreaded tracking in the solr config files.