# java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?)

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am looking a solution of the exception `java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?)` that I am getting in my Logs.

Environment:
Windows Server 2008 R2
JDK 7 update 25

Stack Trace:

> java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum
>   connections reached?): JVM_Bind at 
>   java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
>   at
>   java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.bind(TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.java:101)

The solution that I am getting in all the hits-

```
The solution is to open the registry editor and locate the registry subkey:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters and add a new entry as shown below:

Value Name: MaxUserPort
Value Type: DWORD
Value data: 65534
```

Increasing the number of ephemeral TCP ports in registry, is the right solution? What is the other solution? Is there any other programmatic approach to manage and close the these socket connections?

Comment: Why are you opening these many connections in the first place? Are you not closing the connections after using them?

Comment: It actually looks like you are trying to *listen* on a huge number of sockets, unless you are calling `bind()` yourself for some reason on your client sockets, in which case the simple answer is "don't".

Comment: I followed this solution(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088363/java-net-socketexception-no-buffer-space-available-maximum-connections-reached) that recommended downloading a patch to fix this error.  It didn't work, but updating the MaxUserPort registry key like you suggested did.  Thank You.