# No Buffer Space Available when query Virtuoso locally on Windows

Tags: java, virtuoso

when I query Virtuoso 6 on my local 32bit windows 7 using Jena in a loop, after some iterations I got this error ocasionally:

```
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
```

However I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088363/java-net-socketexception-no-buffer-space-available-maximum-connections-reached) solution, but It didn't solve. Also this error doesn't occur when I query remote SPARQL endpoint (dbpedia.org/sparql)

Is there any Idea?

Comment: Are all your components up to date?  Latest [Virtuoso 6](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews) (why not 7? [Commercial or Open Source](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/features-comparison-matrix/)?), [Virtuoso JDBC Driver, Virtuoso Jena Provider](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider), [Jena](http://jena.apache.org/), [Java 8](http://java.com/), Windows 7 patches, etc?  What's the code of your loop?  Does it close each connection before moving on to the next? More detail is almost always better...