# Jmeter buffer space

Tags: performance, jmeter, load

I'm using J-meter to run some load scenarios on a web-service.

I'm sending a request with **seventy five concurrent users for thirty minutes** but after about five minutes I got this error:

```
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.SoapSampler.sample(SoapSampler.java:271)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1077)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I tried this both solutions but unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you're running JMeter on Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7 you should apply [KB2577795 HotFix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2577795)

If you're running JMeter on Linux, add the following line to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
foo soft nofile 4096
foo hard nofile 65536
```

Where `foo` should be your Linux username

Also set a hard limit by running the next command:

```
ulimit -n 8192
```

Also check out the following references:

- [Increasing the maximum number of tcp/ip connections in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux) - further recommendations on tweaking Linux kernel networking settings
- [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) - JMeter performance tweaks

Comment: I tried this solution but unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Beside this potential duplicate:

- [java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): JVM_Bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088363/java-net-socketexception-no-buffer-space-available-maximum-connections-reached)

Uou should not use SoapSampler anymore.

Read this for up to date way to test Soap WS:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html

Besides, ensure you use last JMeter version.

Comment: I tried this solution but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: What error do you get ? Are you sure the changes have been applied ? Can you describe what you changed ?

Comment: I deployed the new hot fix for windowse server 2008 R2, Increase heap size to the maximum available, increasing the number of max TCP/IP connections, increasing the number of MaxUserPort and decrease the number of concurrent requests